# How do I create an app for anonymous voting in Django?

Tags: django

I am doing an anonymous voting system on django, and this problem has led me to a dead end. Unregistered users can participate in the vote, whose votes I can track by the assigned ID. I have little experience with django, so please do not judge strictly. I will be glad for your help.
When I try to cast anonymously, I get the Cannot assign error :

> "<SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object
> at 0x7f5e345d0d30 >>": "Answer.user" must be a "User" instance.

models.py

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_date = models.DateField()
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1024, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

TYPES_OF_POLLS = (
    ('free_text', 'free text input'),
    ('option', 'only one choice'),
    ('options', 'many choices'),
)

class Question(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    poll_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=TYPES_OF_POLLS, verbose_name='Types of polls')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.text)



class Option(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.question} - {self.text}'

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    one_option = models.ForeignKey(Option, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='option', blank=True)
    many_options = models.ManyToManyField(Option, null=True, blank=True)
    text_input = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.question} - {self.one_option} - {self.many_options} - {self.text_input}  '
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    polls = Poll.objects.all
    context = {'polls':polls}
    return render (request, 'poll_app/home.html', context)

def vote(request, poll_id):
    form = AnswerForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AnswerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_vote = form.save(commit=False)
            new_vote.user = request.user
            new_vote.save()
            return redirect('home')

    context = {
        'form':form
    }
    return render(request, 'poll_app/vote.html', context)
```

Comment: In that case you can not use a `ForeignKey` to the user, you thus remove that. You might store the IP address with an `GenericIPAddressField`, although that of course still can be spoofed with a proxy, so in general there is no good solution to avoid voting multiple times.

Comment: Tell me please @Willem Van Onsem , how can I temporarily assign an ID to a user through cookies, for example for a day?

Comment: but how would that help. Then you will each time create a `User` object? That would result in a huge amount of `User`s that are all "empty", and furthermore cookies are even less safe than an IPAdress, since removing these is quite easy, and one can even use settings to completely ignore these.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem The fact is that this is a test task that I have to perform, the task sounds like this: polls can be passed anonymously, a numeric ID is passed to the API as a user identifier, by which the user's answers to questions are stored; one user can participate in any number of surveys
- getting the polls completed by the user with details on the answers (what is selected) by the unique user ID