# Django poll with many options how to limit visibility?

Tags: django

I am building voting apps in django. I have little experience in programming and in django in particular. And here is the problem I ran into. My application should be able to receive an answer to three types of question:

1. one answer
2. multiple answer options
3. your answer (free text)

Depending on the conditions of the survey, the user should see one of the answer options. But when I post a survey, the user sees all three answer options. How can I fix this? I hope for your help

models.py

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_date = models.DateField()
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1024, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

TYPES_OF_POLLS = (
    ('free_text', 'free text input'),
    ('option', 'only one choice'),
    ('options', 'many choices'),
)

class Question(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    poll_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=TYPES_OF_POLLS, verbose_name='Types of polls')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.text)



class Option(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.question} - {self.text}'

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    one_option = models.ForeignKey(Option, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='option', blank=True)
    many_options = models.ManyToManyField(Option, null=True, blank=True)
    text_input = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.question} - {self.one_option} - {self.many_options} - {self.text_input}  '
```

forms.py

```
class AnswerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ['one_option', 'many_options', 'text_input']
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    polls = Poll.objects.all
    context = {'polls':polls}
    return render (request, 'poll_app/home.html', context)

def vote(request, poll_id):
    form = AnswerForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AnswerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_vote = form.save(commit=False)
            new_vote.user = request.user
            new_vote.save()
            return redirect('home')

    context = {
        'form':form
    }
    return render(request, 'poll_app/vote.html', context)
```

Comment: You can override the forms `__init__` method pass it the `Question` instance and delete the unneeded fields according to the question types `del self.fields['one_option']` etc. But why not have 3 different Answer models (depending on the questions type)? And conditionally pass the form for them.

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat this is what I want to do, depending on the conditions of the question, to provide different options (one answer, several answers, my own answer), but I don’t know how to put it into practice, please help me ahi

Comment: You have a `ForeignKey` from `Question` to `Poll`. Is a poll supposed to have multiple questions?

Comment: @ Abdul Aziz Barkat  No, in one survey there should be one question, is it worth putting OnetoOneField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly since a Survey should have only one question your `ForeignKey` should be a `OneToOneField`:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    poll = models.OneToOneField(Poll, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="question")
    # Remaining fields
```

Now About your answer form you have two ways:

1. Have multiple Answer models which you select according to the Question's `poll_type` field.
2. Set the needed fields in the forms `__init__` method.

Method 1 would be a little long for the answer. But I would suggest using that. Currently in the answer I would show how to use Method 2. You would also need some parts of this in method 1 as your current implementation lacks those things.

First we will override the forms `__init__` method and accept the `Question` instance as a keyword argument, this is also needed to set the queryset of your fields that select options:

```
class AnswerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ['one_option', 'many_options', 'text_input']
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        question = kwargs.pop('question')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if question.poll_type == 'free_text':
            del self.fields['one_option']
            del self.fields['many_options']
        elif question.poll_type == 'option':
            del self.fields['many_options']
            del self.fields['text_input']
            self.fields['one_option'].queryset = question.option_set.all()
        elif question.poll_type == 'options':
            del self.fields['one_option']
            del self.fields['text_input']
            self.fields['many_options'].queryset = question.option_set.all()
```

Now in your view you need to pass the Question to the form:

```
from django.shortcuts get_object_or_404


def vote(request, poll_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, poll_id=poll_id)
    form = AnswerForm(question=question)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AnswerForm(request.POST, question=question)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.instance.question = question
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')

    context = {
        'form':form
    }
    return render(request, 'poll_app/vote.html', context)
```

**Note**: This current implementation would render your options in a select tag, perhaps you would find it better to use the [`RadioSelect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect) and [`CheckboxSelectMultiple`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#checkboxselectmultiple) widgets, in that case you should declare the field yourself inside `__init__` method of the form and specify the widget there.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, now I will try

Comment: thank you very much brother, it works, there is a lot of information for training for me, I did not know that forms can be worked this way

Comment: Is it possible to select multiple answers without holding down the ctrl?

Comment: @MrHow that's just how the select tag works with the multiple attribute. As with the last note in my answer you may find the suggested widgets more appropriate for your use.

Comment: if you have time, please see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66411375/how-do-i-create-an-app-for-anonymous-voting-in-django